# Open multiple workbooks and copy data into one file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to turn up to 12 different Excel files into one PivotTable.

I have dynamic code to turn one worksheet into a Pivot-Table-Form. The result looks a bit like this:

```
| Company  | Model  | Indicator  | Value |  
| Audi     | A1     | AWD        | 2000  |  
| Mercedes | AMG GT | AWD        | 2500  |  
| ...      | ...    | ...        | ...   |
```

(I was not able to apply the "GitHub-flavored markdown format".)

I need the following:

- Open the files with the original data.
- Format files using existing code.
- Copy formatted data into a worksheet in the Excel file, frow which I am running the macro. (This file is called A_11.xlsm.)
- The next file should be opened and the process repeated.
  Copy the data in the same worksheet as previous, directly under the previous data that was added.

I found code that opens the worksheets. How do I integrate this into my Project?

```vb
Sub SelectFiles()

Dim varDateipfade As Variant
Dim intcount As Integer
Dim intAnzahlDateien As Integer

varDateipfade = Application.GetOpenFilename("Datei, *.xls", , "Pkw Dateien auswï¿½hlen", , True)
intAnzahlDateien = UBound(varDateipfade)
MsgBox intAnzahlDateien
For intcount = 1 To intAnzahlDateien
    DatenAuslesen varDateipfade(intcount)
Next

End Sub


Sub DatenAuslesen(varDateipfad As Variant)
Workbooks.Open (varDateipfad)
End Sub
```

The code for the formatting is a bit too long to post.
In case someone needs the name of the Sub.

```vb
Sub Formatierung_original_Dateien()
    'The formatting, that deletes, creates and moves the cells.
End Sub
```

How do I combine the code?

Comment: It looks that the necessary files to be open are in the same folder. Now, are there other such workbooks in the respective folder? I mean, is it necessary to manually select the needed ones (from a larger number of workbooks), or you need a code to process all existing workbooks? Files with other extension may exist without bothering the process of workbooks opening.

Comment: yes they are in the same folder, but I need to select them manually, from 1 to 12 different workbooks.

Comment: OK. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next updated solution:

```
Sub SelectOpenFiles()
 Dim varDateipfade, intCount As Integer, intAnzahlDateien As Integer

 varDateipfade = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Datei (*.xls), *.xls", MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Please, select the workbooks to be processed")

 If Not IsArray(varDateipfade) Then MsgBox "Nothing Selected...", vbInformation, "Abort": Exit Sub 'for the case of no any selection...
 intAnzahlDateien = UBound(varDateipfade)

 For intCount = 1 To intAnzahlDateien 'you need to iterate between the returned aray elements
     DatenAuslesen CStr(varDateipfade(intCount)) 'send the workbook full name as parameter...
 Next
End Sub

Sub DatenAuslesen(varDateipfad As String)
   Dim wb As Workbook
   
   Set wb = Workbooks.Open(varDateipfad)
    Debug.Print wb.Sheets.count: Stop
    'do whatever you need with the workbook...
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I have a short question. I added the code to copy the data into my main file, but when I try to add the workbook.close methode, I get the error: `Subscript out of range`. The Code I try to use is `Application.Workbooks(varDateipfad).Activate  ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)`. Can you help me fixing this problem?

Comment: @Elias Well, it depends on where you try closing it, but use the created object `wb` (to be set)... If you do that in `DatenAuslesen` sub, it should work. If you want doing it in the mail sub, you must declare `wb` on top of the module (in the declarations area) as `Public wb As Workbook`. And delete its declaration from `DatenAuslesen` ... `Application.Workbooks(varDateipfad).Activate` does not make any sense. `varDateipfad` is an array. Even if you use `varDateipfad(intCount)`, it contains the wb **full name**, which is not recognized by `Application.Workbooks`, which uses the workbook name.

Comment: @Elias Then, selecting, activating only consumes Excel resources, not bringing any benefit. You should avoid that. Using `wb.Close False` is shorter, does not need any activation and is easy to be used from any place (if `wb` is declared where I suggested and it is `Set`)...

Comment: thanks for your help, I was not fast enough with reading your comment. I now added `Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True` at the end of the `DatenAuslesen` Sub. I got it working, but I am very happy that you could help me out.